# Как организовать вызов функции в автономном режиме в определенное время [javascript]?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase

Имеется веб-приложение написанное на vue.js. База данных, хостинг, сервис авторизации используется от firebase.  Столкнулся с проблемой, что необходимо выполнять функцию в определенное время, при чем без загрузки в этот момент страницы, т.е. оффлайн, когда ни у кого из пользователей приложение не открыто. В сети информации не нашел (возможно не то гуглил, так же было бы неплохо узнать как правильно данный вид функций называется)
Заранее благодарю за предложения по решению данного вопроса!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: К сожалению, эта возможность доступна только для Google Cloud Firestore с тарифным планом Blaze

Comment: ну да, за расширенный функционал надо платить. у приложения есть какой-то бэкенд или оно полностью на сервисах firebase?

Comment: полностью, добавлен только другой домен. Дело в том, я использую Firebase Hosting, а не Cloud Firestore.